# How to generate random velocity vectors that can only move an object forward within a valid arc?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, physics, computer-science, 3d

I have an object with known coordinates in in 3D but on the ground (`z=0`). The object has a direction vector. My goal is to move this object on the ground (so `z` stays `0`) using its direction vector and via randomly-generated velocity vectors with one condition: I want to ensure that the generate velocity vector can only move the object within a "valid arc", defined in degrees with respect to the direction vector of the object. More specifically, the way I determine valid range is by ensuring that the new position is within 45 degrees of the old object's direction vector (-45 degrees to the left and +45 degrees to the right). Can someone write a pseudocode on how I can achieve this?

Here's my attempt to do this but this doesn't seem to be the correct way to help me achieve what I want:

```
object_dir = object_position # the direction could be the same as the object's coortinates
while True:
    vel_vec=[uniform(-max_vel, max_vel), uniform(-max_vel, max_vel)] # generate a random velocity vector
    new_pos = object_dir + vel_vec # compute a new position (and/or object direction vector) for the object
    if (compute_angle(new_pos, object_dir) < 45 or compute_angle(new_pos, object_dir) > 315):
        break
```

Comment: Why `object_dir = object_position`? What is the point of using the name `object_dir` if it is just another name for `object_position`? Do you have any concept of what a _direction_ vector is, what a _position_ vector is, and what the difference is between them? Or do you think there is no difference? The meaning of the words matters, because without agreed-upon meanings we have no way to know what you want.

Comment: @DavidK Sorry for making you confused. `object_dir` is an arbitrary direction vector. In other words, imagine you see an image a billiard ball in isolation captured with a very fast camera. You cannot be sure whether the ball is moving or is still and you imagine the ball moving in pretty much any direction. In my case I set `object_dir = object_position` because I was assuming the object has started moving from the origin and is "supposed" to continue in that direction

Comment: "position vector" is not really a vector but just an indicator for where the object is whereas direction vector dictates what the object location would be at `t+1`. However, in my case I want to generate another, random, direction vector and use this new direction vector to move the object

Comment: A position vector really is a vector, but it's used for a different purpose than a typical direction vector. The assumption that the direction vector equals the position vector because the object came from the origin is a valid assumption only if you also assume the object moves along a straight path during each discrete time step and if you only consider the situation at the end of the first time step. The assumption is wrong at the start of the first time step and probably wrong at the end of the second time step (since it probably changed direction).

Comment: And then there's `camera_dir`. Why should that have any relationship to the object's motion? Is the motion of a race car on the track affected by someone looking at it from the stands?

Comment: @DavidK Here I am assuming a super simple, non-physics-based, setting where the object moves along `object_dir` on a straight path to convey the point on what my prob,em setting is and what I want. In short, all I need is to generate random velocity vectors on an arc, certain degree wide. The direction vector passes through the arc in the middle.

Comment: The pseoducode is a pretty rough thing and I know it does not work after I tried it. I removed `camera_dir` as I don't need it here in this example, it's from the past.

Comment: If I can change direction by $36$ degrees to the left in every time step, I can travel along the sides of a decagon and come back to where I started in $10$ time steps, and repeat this indefinitely. Is that within your rules? Or is there something special about the first motion you make, that all later direction vectors have to be within $45$ degrees of the very first one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126681/discussion-between-david-k-and-amir).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I think you just want the direction of motion in each time step to be less than $45$ degrees from the direction of motion in the previous time step.
That means you can completely reverse direction if you take enough steps to do it.
You can also eventually travel into all four quadrants of the plane regardless of how you started out from the origin.

Moreover, the *velocity* of the object is a vector in the *direction of travel*
of the object. The only distinction I might make between a "direction vector" and velocity is that a "direction vector" might be normalized to a certain length.
Often the direction vector will be defined as the unit-length vector in the same direction as the velocity.

If you can find the angle between arbitrary vectors, not just unit vectors, I don't even see a reason to include any "direction vector" in your code. Just consider velocity.

So I would ignore positions entirely when computing the angle.
But you need to remember what the direction vector was in the previous time step.

---

Here's one way you could do it. In each time step, you compute a new `vel_vec`. You then compute the angle between `vel_vec` and `previous_vel_vec` (which was the velocity vector in the previous time step). If that angle is in the permitted range, accept `vel_vec`, otherwise try again.

When you finally find an acceptable `vel_vec`, *then* you use it to compute a new position. And then make the assignment `previous_vel_vec = vel_vec` so that you will have the correct `previous_vel_vec` for the next time step.

---

But I would do it quite differently.
For one thing, I don't like the fact that the velocity is more likely to be at about a $45$ degree angle from an axis than parallel to an axis regardless of what the valid arc is at that time.
This happens because you distributed the velocity uniformly over a square, and there is more area in the parts of a square within $\pm22.5$ degrees of a diagonal than within $\pm22.5$ degrees of a centerline parallel to a side.
I would prefer to distribute the direction uniformly within the limits of the valid arc.

I would keep track of the "compass direction" of the velocity (that is, what angle it makes with the $x$ axis in the $x,y$ plane).
Then, at each time step, to find the new velocity I just add a random number uniformly distributed between $-\frac\pi4$ and $\frac\pi4$ (measuring the angle in radians -- if you insist on using degrees, which you will continually have to convert to radians anyway for every trig function, then you want a uniform distribution
between $-45$ and $45$).
Take another random number $\rho$ uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1,$
and multiply `max_vel` by $\sqrt{\rho},$ because that's how we get a uniform distribution within a circular sector.
(As [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/218/139123) observes,
we get a uniform distribution within an entire circle if we let the angle range over $360$ degrees; we are just restricting the angle in order to sample a sector).

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for your answer. I know the general approach for achieving what I need (and you complemented that for me too). However, I need a more algorithmic and deterministic answer. It would be great if you are able to write a pseudocode with a more precise way of computing things to achieve what I need as well

Answer (score 1):

Pick a random angle $\theta$ between $-45^\circ$ and $+45^\circ$ (or equivalently $-\pi/4$ and $+\pi/4$), and rotate the current direction vector by that angle around the $z$ axis.

If the surface your object is moving on is not perpendicular to the $z$ axis, rotate around the unit surface normal of that surface.

One very efficient way to do this is to use the [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula),
$$\vec{v}_\text{new} = \vec{v}_\text{old} \cos \theta + (\vec{n} \times \vec{v}) \sin\theta + \vec{n} \left(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{v}_\text{old} \right)(1 - \cos\theta)$$
where $\vec{n}$ is the surface unit normal vector ($\lVert\vec{n}\rVert = 1$), $\vec{v}_\text{old}$ is the old direction/velocity vector, and $\vec{v}_\text{new}$ is the direction/velocity vector rotated by $\theta$ around unit axis vector $\vec{n}$.

---

Here is an example implementation in Python:

```
import math
import random

def turn(direction, normal, max_degrees, distribution=None):
    # Cartesian coordinate components of the two vectors
    dx, dy, dz = direction
    nx, ny, nz = normal

    # Make sure the normal vector is an unit vector.
    n = math.sqrt(nx*nx + ny*ny + nz*nz)
    if n == 0.0:
        raise ValueError("Cannot turn around a zero vector!")
    if n != 1.0:
        nx = nx / n
        ny = ny / n
        nz = nz / n

    # Pick an uniform random number between -1 and +1,
    u = random.Random().uniform(-1, +1)
    # apply the distribution function (0..1 -> 0..1) if any is specified,
    if distribution is not None:
        u = math.copysign(distribution(abs(u)), u)
    # and scale to radians, since that's what math.sin and math.cos take,
    rads = u * abs(max_degrees) * math.pi / 180.0
    s = math.sin(rads)
    c = math.cos(rads)

    # Cross product between normal (nx,ny,nz) and direction (dx,dy,dz)
    cx = ny*dz - nz*dy
    cy = nz*dx - nx*dz
    cz = nx*dy - ny*dx

    # Dot product between normal and direction, scaled by (1-cos)
    d = (nx*dx + ny*dy + nz*dz) * (1 - c)

    # Apply Rodrigues' rotation formula to dx,dy,dz
    rx = dx*c + cx*s + d*nx
    ry = dy*c + cy*s + d*ny
    rz = dz*c + cz*s + d*nz

    return rx,ry,rz


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uniform = random.Random().uniform

    # Pick a random direction on the XY plane,
    xyangle = uniform(0, 2*math.pi)
    direction = (math.cos(xyangle), math.sin(xyangle), 0)

    print("Original direction: (%.6f, %.6f, %.6f)" % direction)

    # Deflected direction can vary by up to 45 degrees.
    deflected = turn(direction, [0,0,1], 45.0)
    print("Turned direction: (%.6f, %.6f, %.6f)" % deflected)

    # Calculate and report the actual deflection angle.
    theta = math.acos( (direction[0]*deflected[0] + direction[1]*deflected[1] + direction[2]*deflected[2])
                       / math.sqrt( (direction[0]*direction[0] + direction[1]*direction[1] + direction[2]*direction[2])
                                  * (deflected[0]*deflected[0] + deflected[1]*deflected[1] + deflected[2]*deflected[2]) ))
    print("Turning angle %.3f degrees" % (theta * 180.0 / math.pi))
```

You can run the above example to see a random direction (in the XY plane) rotated up to $45^\circ$ around the $z$ axis.

The optional `distribution` argument to the `turn` function is a single-variate function applied to an uniform random number between $0$ and $1$ to get the desired distribution (also between $0$ and $1$).  An extremely common one in Python would be `lambda x: x**N` where `N` is some constant number greater than 1, say around 2.0, so that small angles are more common than large angles.  (The larger `N` is, the more common small angles are compared to large angles.  Conversely, `N` between $0$ and $1$ would make larger turns more common than small turns the closer `N` is to zero.)

Alternatively, in Python one could use [random.Random().betavariate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) or [random.Random().gauss()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) instead of random.Random().uniform() to generate a deflection scale value between $-1$ and $+1$ in the desired (symmetric?) distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your solution at some point later and select it as final answer if things work fine.